# jQuery Ajax call exception restricting subsequent ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Dears, I am doing multiple ajax calls in my web application & few library calls are happening as part of APM out of which intermittently the AJAX call is failing with "replace of undefined" then the subsequent ajax calls are failing. I have to refresh the page then only the ajax call is working. If I initiate some ajax, by default ajax error method only it is calling.

What is the best approach to handle this ajax subsequent calls without page refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might sound rudely obvious, but - how about fixing the code that triggers this error? Sure, you can wrap your jquery calls into some kind of safety net catch, but it might be just hiding the bigger issue that you've got on your plate.

Comment: `replace` of undefined cries of something that expects a string (and then try to massage it); how about providing some default value to that? like n/a or something.

Comment: These ajax calls are triggered by APM library which we don't have any control of which element is cause the issue.. even this exception is intermittent only.

Comment: Could you show the code on your side (that you do control) which starts this chain of calls?